# 1 select com duas colunas

Tags: mysql, sql

Bom, estou realizando um select entre duas datas que me retorna dois valores.

1. Quantidade de compras pagas em DINHEIRO.
2. Quantidade de compras pagas em CARTÃO DE CREDITO.

Estou fazendo da seguinte forma,

```
SELECT COUNT(FORMA_PAGAMENTO) AS 'DINHEIRO' FROM ESTOQUE WHERE FORMA_PAGAMENTO = 'dinheiro' AND DATA BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-02-13' 
UNION   
SELECT (COUNT(FORMA_PAGAMENTO) AS 'CARTÃO DE CREDITO' FROM ESTOQUE WHERE FORMA_PAGAMENTO = 'Cartão de Crédito' AND DATA BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-02-13';
```

O problema é que esta me retornando os dois valores na mesma coluna, e eu preciso que seja em campos diferentes:

```
**DINHEIRO**      **CARTÃO DE CREDITO** 

    X                     Y
```

Fiz diversas pesquisas e não encontrei algo relacionado. A tabela que esta sendo realizada o select não possui nenhum relacionamento.

Comment: Como a melhor resposta já foi escolhida, vou dar só uma dica daqui do forum. Nas tuas tags da pergunta está "javascript" e "php", mas ela só diz respeito a derivados de SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode ser da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT (
    SELECT COUNT(FORMA_PAGAMENTO)
    FROM ESTOQUE
    WHERE FORMA_PAGAMENTO = 'dinheiro'
    AND DATA BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-02-13' 
) AS 'DINHEIRO',
(
    SELECT (COUNT(FORMA_PAGAMENTO))
    FROM ESTOQUE
    WHERE FORMA_PAGAMENTO = 'Cartão de Crédito'
    AND DATA BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-02-13'
) AS 'CARTÃO DE CREDITO'
```

Comment: Cara, não tinha pensado dessa forma, e acaba sendo o mesmo resultado. Muito obrigado também.

Answer (score 1):

Como o intervalo de datas e o mesmo, você pode fazer um SUM utilizando um CASE WHEN , desta forma você consegue os resultados em colunas separadas. De acordo com o que você postou, a query ficaria assim:

```
SELECT SUM(case when FORMA_PAGAMENTO = 'dinheiro' then 1 else 0 end) as dinheiro, 
 SUM(case when FORMA_PAGAMENTO = 'Cartão de Crédito' then 1 else 0 end) as cartao
from ESTOQUE WHERE DATA BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-02-13'
```

Comment: Cara, do fundo do meu coração muito obrigado. Era exatamente esse resultado que eu precisava e deu certo.

Muito obrigado mesmo.